# How to change active menu item on horizontal scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a single page with a fixed menu on top of it, in which the active tab would change depending on horizontal scroll position. As a beginner, I would like to figure out **what is wrong in my code** instead of using a jQuery pluggin. Any help to correct my JavaScript code would be greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test scrollLeft</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1 /jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<nav>
      <ul id="menu">
        <li><a id="one" class="active" href="#foo">Accueil</a></li>
        <li><a id="two" href="#bar">Infos</a></li>
        <li><a id="three" href="#baz">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

<section class="page" id="foo">
      <h2>Accueil</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</section> 

<section class="page" id="bar">
  <h2>Infos</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</section>

<section class="page" id="baz">
      <h2>Contact</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</section>

<div class="result"><span id="result"></span></div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
height: 100%; 
overflow-y: hidden; 
margin:0px; padding: 0 0 0 0;
} 
body {
  width:4500px; 
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
}
.page {
  height:100%; 
  float: left; 
  width: 1500px;
} 
.page h2 {
  padding: 50px 0 0 20px;
}
.page p {
  width: 500px; 
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}
div.page p {
      height: 900px; 
      margin-top: 50px;
}
div.result {
      margin: 10px; 
      width: 100px; 
      height: 100px; 
      margin: 5px; 
      float: left; 
      color: white;
      background-color: blue;
      position: fixed;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
} 
#foo {
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
}   
#bar {
  background-color: #c4c4c4;
}
#baz {
  background-color: #a9a9a9;
}
#menu {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #d68aa5;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#menu li {
    float: left;
    display: block; 
}
#menu a {
    display: block; 
    padding: 5px 25px 7px 25px;
    transition: 1s all ease;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none; 
}   
#menu a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
.active {background-color: #000; color: #fff!important;}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

  $(window).mousemove(function () {

 var currentScrollLeft = $(window).scrollLeft();
 $("#result").html(currentScrollLeft);     

     switch(currentScrollLeft) {
    case (($currentScrollLeft >= 0) && ($currentScrollLeft <= 1499)):
        $('#one').addClass('active');
        break;

     case (($currentScrollLeft >= 1500) && ($currentScrollLeft <= 2999)):
        $('#two').addClass('active');
        break;

     case (($currentScrollLeft >= 3000) && ($currentScrollLeft <= 4500)):
        $('#three').addClass('active');
        break;
  }
   });
});
```

Comment: better you'll create an example in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? you want to change the class on `mouse over` or `mouse move` or on `click`? What are your active class and deactive class?

Comment: Having both left and right set to 0 is bound to cause problems. Try removing right:0 from #menu.

Comment: To be more precise, I want to change the active class of my menu dynamically, depending on horizontal scroll, wether it is by rolling the mouse wheel or using the trackpad of my computer.

Comment: I have updated my code and provided an example here : http://jsfiddle.net/STF75/sHKsL/   As you can see, the active menu tab only updates on mouse click but not when scrolling left or right. Any idea of what's wrong in my JavaScript code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sHKsL/3/) link, here i have updated you source to fix the problem. i hope this may help you.

instead of switch statement

```
switch(cond){}
```

you can use if statement

```
if(cond){}
```

If statements can reduce more problems because switch can't operate with dynamic variable values which means you can only use constant values in switch.

Comment: I thank you very much for this very useful answer. I realize that the "switch" statement was not adapted to my needs. I also noticed that the scroll function has changed the behavior of the navigation menu, since the active class only applies to the next tab when next section is reached. Any idea how to make a smooth transition between the tabs?